# Shall I use the structs as a Parameterized Constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

This is my sample code. I used it like this, but I had an error from **//error-line**.

The following error appeared:

> Variable has incomplete type 'std::TestCpp:: TestString'

```
class TestCpp{
    public:
        any value;
        struct TestString;

        TestCpp(TestString Value){ // error
            this->value = static_cast<any>(Value);
            cout << Value;
        }

};
```

Comment: Because you are using  the object ``Value`` in your function. And the compiler does not know anything about it. You want to define your function after ``struct TestString`` is defined.

Comment: Where is `struct TestString` defined?

Comment: What are you even trying to accomplish?

Comment: This might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279810/passing-a-struct-as-a-constructor-parameter-in-c

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

Comment: I Just want to set the Value's datatype as a TestStrin(struct) @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica

Comment: I defined the TestString below the TestCpp class.@MichaelChourdakis

Comment: @AmbroseJesuraj You did not define it. You declared it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an instance of `TestString` in the constructor of `TestCpp` before it has been defined. You should first define `TestString`, then define the constructor of `TestCpp`. My guess is you don't want to define `TestString` where you declared it. To achieve that, you can do this by defining the constructor of `TestCpp` in a source file for instance.

```
// header file
struct TestCpp
{
    std::any _value;
    struct TestString;
    TestCpp(TestString); // declare here, define in source file    
};

// source file
#include "header_file"

struct TestCpp::TestString { /* ... */ };

TestCpp::TestCpp(TestString) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: How to I directly use the TestCpp struct inside the parameterized constructor of TestCpp.

Comment: And also I have one doubt, Shall I declare a Struct inside the source file

Comment: No. how to use the TestCpp struct inside a C++ class file constructer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207252/discussion-between-mfnx-and-ambrose-jesuraj).

Comment: Got a Answer from @mfnx.